# Hugo changed to post-stub-description instead of post-date

Tags: hugo

So I recently switched to a new distro and moved my page over which uses Hugo.  Before on my main page Hugo would render the main page in a list showing the title + date:

```
Title1 / Date
Title2 / Date
```

Now it renders as:

```
Title1 / description 
Title2 / description
```

I've never had to edit the index.html or .xml before Hugo would do all that once I told it to build the page, but below is example of what the source looks like now.  So instead of post-stub-title / post-stub-description.  I want it to be back to post-stub-title / post-date.  If that makes sense.  I would rather not edit this by hand every single time.

I also don't remember the previous version of Hugo I was using sadly but now I'm using 4.2.

```
</li>

        <li class="post-stub">
<a href="https://foobar.com/2018/04/16/foo1/">
    <h4 class="post-stub-title">Foo1 &#43; Blah</h4>

        <p class="post-stub-description">Attempted hugo page</p>


</a>
```

If any of those Hugo gurus out there knows a way to fix that I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

So I spun up a Debian box which uses 0.18.1 and that fixed the issue. Which I don’t really understand but it works now.